# Vostro 3400 touchpad multiple gesture and two finger scrolling not working

Tags: multi-touch, touchpad, dell

I recently bought a dell vostro 3400 i3 with 4 gb ram. Everything works smooth as silk and I am using maverick but I can't get two finger scrolling and multiple gestures such as zoom etc which it says it supports. Can anyone help ? I have installed gsynaptics and enabled scrolling yet it doesnot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Toshiba U400 has the same problem.  Even install gpointing-device-settings didn't work, although at least the option to enable it wasn't greyed out there.

In the end, I found this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1443291), which highlighted this little shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# list of synaptics device properties http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect4
# list  current synaptics device properties: xinput list-props '"AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint"'
#
sleep 5 #added delay... 
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 125
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 0         # Below width 1 finger touch, above width simulate 2 finger touch. - value=pad-pixels
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0   # vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling - values: 0=disable 1=enable
exit
```

It works for some models, not for others, however.  Good luck.

Comment: Well the forum worked somewhat but the zoom and other gestures didnot

Comment: Yep, I have no idea how to get the other gestures working.  Perhaps someone skilled in uTouch can help.  Your question was only about two-fingered scrolling, so I didn't look any further.  Check out http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/utouch/

Comment: I've been using this script happily for a month and now my multitouch 2 finger scrolling has gone wild: the mouse cursor runs everywhere :/