# Touchpad Two-finger Scroll Configuration

Tags: drivers, touchpad, compatibility, dell-studio-xps-16

This all started with me trying to get 2-finger scroll working. In Windows, I got used to it. So I found a thread that said to run these commands:

```
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinW=5
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinZ=48
```

It kinda worked, when I put one finger extremely close to the other. So another thread said to fine-tune the MinW and MinZ by doing `synclient -m 150`, where I got the error "Can't access shared memory area. SHMConfig disabled?"

So I set off to enable SHM Config. I found another post that said to edit my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file and add `Option          "SHMConfig"             "on"` - so that's in there, and I still get that error. My mouse is all over the place almost any time I touch it at this point!

Answer (score 1):

I have dell vostro and although the mouse settings lets me enable two-finger scrolling. It didnot work. I asked twice about this and got to this workaround.

[Vostro 3400 touchpad multiple gesture and two finger scrolling not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18576/vostro-3400-touchpad-multiple-gesture-and-two-finger-scrolling-not-working)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/33877/two-finger-scrolling-not-working

I added the following line to `/etc/profile` and now it works. May be you could try that.

`xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 40`