# Two finger scrolling on touchpad

Tags: 10.04, laptop, touchpad

I can scroll with 2 fingers with my touchpad on Win7 but when I switch to Ubuntu 10.04 it doesn't work, the option is greyed out.

Could anyone help?

- My touchpad is Synaptics V7.2 PS/2 Port

[image: Can't click]

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more info? Such as PC Make/Model and the like...

Comment: What kind of touch pad is it?

Comment: @Roland Taylor I don't know where I can look for this info?

Comment: On Win7, you can check device info or even the touchpad settings. It will say something like "Synaptics Touchpad blablabla".

Comment: I have installed gsynaptics... try it!

Comment: Have you looked at System->Preferences->Mouse, Touchpad page?

Comment: @enzotib @Roland i also found Synaptics Touchpad v7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried few solutions but it didn't work however I found out that you can scroll placing one finger to the right of touchpad and going up or down. [image]

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu this option is disabled by default, go to System > Preferences > Mouse, in the Touchpad tab select "Two-finger scrolling" and that's done.
[image: Select Two-finger scrolling]

Comment: I can't click on it http://i.stack.imgur.com/oUP7Q.png

Comment: Oh! I see your problem, it's because you're using Ubuntu 10.04 and this version still has some incompatibility issues with touchpads. I will look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinW=5
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinZ=48
```

to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file and reboot (loging out and in again should also work).

Comment: **This Just Worked™ out of the box for me** (Lenovo T400) - but the first time I tested it I'd run a bunch of other commands first and the resulting messed-up settings meant this didn't work. To try this properly I recommend restarting X first.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu forums, you could try something like [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419833).

```
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If my previous answer didn't work for any reason it means there is a compatibility issue with the touchpad, to fix it you need to enable SHMConfig, to do it type in the terminal:

`gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, in the file that will open add it:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "enable synaptics SHMConfig"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "SHMConfig" "on"
EndSection
```

If there is a Section "ServerLayout" in the file, add this line into it:

```
InputDevice     "SynapticsMouse1" "AlwaysCore"
```

Save the file, close it and reboot your system.

Then install these packages from the [Universe Repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu):

- gsynaptics
- synclient
- xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

After a reboot try enabling Two-finger scrolling through Mouse Preferences and if it's still impossible try in the terminal:

`synclient -l` , that will list every touchpad settings possible, then try some settings with this structure: `setting=1` to enable and `setting=0` to disable.

Eventually, if you didn't achieve nothing, see this [Touchpad Troubleshooting Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad/PreMaverick#Troubleshooting) and if any, report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was using 10.04. Basically I think there is a bug which doesnot show two finger scrolling option although it works in older package. I think you can enable the graphical button from gconf but it didnot help me then. Here are some questions I posted with some solutions:

[Touchpad two finger sensivity problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35977/touchpad-two-finger-sensivity-problem)

[Vostro 3400 touchpad multiple gesture and two finger scrolling not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18576/vostro-3400-touchpad-multiple-gesture-and-two-finger-scrolling-not-working)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/33877/two-finger-scrolling-not-working